# IF: command not found, windows cmd

Tags: c++, cmd

I am trying to run the following command using c++

```
IF exist C:/Users/Alacran/Desktop/ESP/001/ echo exists ELSE mkdir C:/Users/Alacran/Desktop/ESP/001/ && echo created
```

but I am getting the error "IF: command not found"

here is what I am doing in my c++ program

```
//string id is defined
....
stringstream ss;
ss << "IF exist C:/Users/Alacran/Desktop/ESP/" << id.c_str() << "/ echo exists ELSE mkdir " << "C:/Users/Alacran/Desktop/ESP/" << id.c_str() << " && echo created";
string info = ss.str();
char* path = new char(info.length() + 1);
strcpy(path, info.c_str());
system(path);
string instance;
cout << "Enter instance number" << endl;
getline(cin, instance, '\n');
....
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't use use [mkdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx) function for directory creation?

Comment: No need for the `path` variable at all. You're wrongly trying to use it as an array, and leaking memory if it's not deleted (and properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command

```
IF exist C:/Users/Alacran/Desktop/ESP/001/ echo exists ELSE mkdir C:/Users/Alacran/Desktop/ESP/001/ && echo created
```

has syntax issues and logic issues. Try this instead:

```
(md "C:\Users\Alacran\Desktop\ESP\001" 2>nul) && echo created || echo exists
```

Also, instead of trying to issue such a command from C++, just create the directory via some appropriate API, for example using Boost filesystem.